# Restful web services Documentation

Tags: 8

I am looking for complete and updated documentation for Restful web services.

For example, for the user login, we have to post the following data.

```
POST: http://example.com/user/login?_format=json
Content-type: application/json
Data: { "name": "admin", "pass": "myPassword" }
Response: 200 OK
```

This will properly log in via cookie authentication, and return a result similar to this.

```
    {
      "current_user": {
        "uid":"1",
        "roles":["authenticated"],
        "name":"admin"
      },
      "csrf_token":"abc123",
      "logout_token":"def456"
    }
```

How do I log out the user I just logged in with?

I found [RESTful Web Services module overview](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/overview), but I still don't understand how to log out.

Using the following request gets back a 403 Forbidden error.

```
POST: http://example.com/user/logout?_format=json
Content-type: application/json
Data: { "name": "admin" }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: They are the same URLs you normally use on Drupal, so the one to log out is user/logout, and the one to see the profile of the user #1 is user/1.

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno, Can you please tell me how can I logout using RestWS. I have tried several ways but no one is working.

Comment: Core REST modules are not the same as the RestWS contrib module.

Comment: hi @visabhishek, which drupal 8 version you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/javascript-and-drupal-8-restful-web-services#users) you can do like this.

**Logout**

```
GET http://example.com/user/logout
Content-type: text/html
200 - OK
```

Note: Do not pass **"?_format=json"** it is not accepting.

Comment: I am using Drupal 8.3.1. 

Thanks vijay above code is working fine, How can I get success message or any return value after logout.

Comment: No visabhishek, currently drupal not providing any logout message for REST, Even it's return type is "text/html". Base on return status code you need to show message from client side.